# TecDoc webservice with PHP

Tags: php, web-services

I want to use `TecDoc webservice` in my php application can anyone give me a good documentation about it, I was searching alot but I still can't find a good and clear one.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I found this code under this [link](https://www.wsdltophp.com/Wsdls/9c0443e1608d1d04c6ef7eba13a74554/TecDoc-1-0-1-1-1-1-1-1-0-0) and this [site](http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-2-0/test2/index.html) that helps you test the functions provided by the `TecDoc webservice`.
So I tried the `getMarkById` function and it worked fine (on the site), then I tried it in my php application this way (with the same parameters):

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(-1);
/**
 * Load autoload
 */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/TecDocAutoload.php';
/**
 * TecDoc Informations
 */
define('TECDOC_WSDL_URL','http://webservicepilot.tecdoc.net/pegasus-2-0/wsdl/TecdocToCat');
define('TECDOC_USER_LOGIN','');
define('TECDOC_USER_PASSWORD','');
/**
 * Wsdl instanciation infos
 */
$wsdl = array();
$wsdl[TecDocWsdlClass::WSDL_URL] = TECDOC_WSDL_URL;
$wsdl[TecDocWsdlClass::WSDL_CACHE_WSDL] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE;
$wsdl[TecDocWsdlClass::WSDL_TRACE] = true;
if(TECDOC_USER_LOGIN !== '')
    $wsdl[TecDocWsdlClass::WSDL_LOGIN] = TECDOC_USER_LOGIN;
if(TECDOC_USER_PASSWORD !== '')
    $wsdl[TecDocWsdlClass::WSDL_PASSWD] = TECDOC_USER_PASSWORD;
// etc....
/**
 * Examples
 */


/******************************
 * Example for TecDocServiceGet
 */
$tecDocServiceGet = new TecDocServiceGet($wsdl);

if($tecDocServiceGet->getMarkById(new TecDocStructMarkByIdRequest(
    'de',
    'de',
    true,
    10,
    20276
)))
    var_dump($tecDocServiceGet->getResult()->data);
else
    print_r($tecDocServiceGet->getLastError());
```

But I get this result:

```
object(TecDocStructMarkByIdResponse)[5]
  public 'data' => null
  public 'status' => int 401
  public 'statusText' => string 'Access not allowed' (length=18)
  private 'result' (TecDocWsdlClass) => null
  private 'lastError' (TecDocWsdlClass) => null
  private 'internArrayToIterate' (TecDocWsdlClass) => null
  private 'internArrayToIterateIsArray' (TecDocWsdlClass) => null
  private 'internArrayToIterateOffset' (TecDocWsdlClass) => null
```

I don't know why I'm not allowed to access this function !!

Comment: go with this link https://www.scribd.com/document/233210057/TecDoc-WebService

Comment: anotherone : https://github.com/mak-it/tec_doc

Comment: Thnx but it's not allowed in our country to use any paimenet methode, we don't have cards for it, so I can't buy the documentation

Comment: I want php client if that possible.

Answer (score 1):

1.4 Access Control
In each request function there is a parameter provider of type integer. TecDoc
assigns this number to each mandator. It is evaluated to authenticate the mandator
and authorize the request together with the ip address of the request. The static
ip address or addresses of the mandator are configured by TecDoc based on the
information provided by the mandator.
The webservice "addDynamicAddress()" can be used. It is the first webservice
described within this document.

As it's been said in the documentation, you need this Provider Id in order to read data.